# Как сделать чтобы на мобильной версии FancyBox не закрывался при нажатии на область вокруг модального окна?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

Плагин FancyBox.
Как сделать на мобильной версии чтобы окно не закрывалось при нажатии на свободную область?
И можно ли убрать чтобы модальное окно не закрывалось если его тащить вверх/вниз?

Comment: https://fancyapps.com/playground/1W2

Comment: На это влияет функция shouldClose?

Comment: не обязательно ее использовать, она ими приведена для тонкой настройки закрытия. достаточно опции click: false. добавил упрощенный пример в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Немного изменил пример с их сайта:

[fancyapps.com/playground/1W2](https://fancyapps.com/playground/1W2)

```js
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="trigger-modal"]', {
  closeButton: true,
  dragToClose: false,
  click: false
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0/dist/fancybox.umd.js"></script>

<h1 class="mt-12 mb-8 px-6 text-center text-lg md:text-2xl font-semibold">
  Fancybox true modal
</h1>

<p class="text-center">
  <a
    data-fancybox="trigger-modal"
    href="#modal-test"
    class="px-6 pt-2 pb-3 text-xl bg-indigo-500 text-white rounded-full font-semibold"
    >Click me</a
  >
</p>

<div id="modal-test" style="display: none">
  <p class="mb-4 text-lg leading-8">
    Interdum et malesuada fames a
  </p>

</div>
```